# How can i add Libraries to Browser Console?

Tags: browser, mongoose, console

Can i add any library such as mongoose, to my browser console (even if it is temporary and gets finished on refreshing). So that i could access its function from browser console. Any plugins is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the script tag in the page that has been loaded from browser console by

```
document.head.innerHTML+="<script src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Automattic/mongoose/master/bin/mongoose.js'></script>";
```

And for more native way,

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Automattic/mongoose/master/bin/mongoose.js'; // url of the mongoose.js
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

It will be available in console using

```
>> mongoose;
<- Object { Error: MongooseError(), Schema: Schema(), Types: Object, VirtualType: VirtualType(), SchemaType: SchemaType(), utils: Object, Document: Document() }
```

Comment: page created is actually REST Client App. and I want to include this library into its Console Browser.

Comment: Which client are you using? @Mohit

Comment: Mozilla REST Client Plugin